# Remove duplicates app name(String) from ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to get the list of non repeated app names ,How can i know that my list view already has the same name . I have tried the following code but i am only getting the duplicates app name since there are running more than one processes of a single app and at this situation i only want to show the app name for only ones. 
How can i do that ..??

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (null == convertView)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) m_oContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    } else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    AndroidAppProcess androidAppProcess = m_processesList.get(position);
    //getItem(position);
    TextView processName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    ImageView appIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    if (androidAppProcess != null)
    {
        try
        {

            String proName= (String) m_oContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(m_oContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(androidAppProcess.getPackageName(), m_oContext.getPackageManager().GET_META_DATA));
//           if( processName !=null && !m_processesList.contains(proName))
            if( processName !=null && !proName.equalsIgnoreCase((String)processName.getText()))

            {
                if(!proName.equals("Battery Optimizer"))
                {
                    processName.setText(proName);
                    appIcon.setImageDrawable(m_oContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(androidAppProcess.getPackageName()));
                }
            }
            //TODO: maintain icon size to avoid OOM error
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
       {
           processName.setText(androidAppProcess.getPackageName());
           Drawable res = m_oContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, m_oContext.getTheme());
           appIcon.setImageDrawable(res);
       }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please put the screen shot?

Comment: Simple apply HashSet<String> will solve your problem

Comment: @S.W.  HashSet can solve it but i would have to use it inside the getView() of adapter ...can you plz elaborate how to use it

Comment: Make `m_processesList` a HashSet instead of an ArrayList

Comment: @cricket_007 yup ...let me try this

Comment: @cricket_007 but when we change `m_processesList` to HashSet we cann't get item at position

Comment: Simply apply the HashSet in Constructor and after adding all names, simply convert the HashSet into List and store it as a global variable in the adapter class

Comment: Why do you do this at getView? Wouldn't it be easier to check the items at the time when they're added? For example, if you want to add an item to an ArrayList, check the ArrayList for matches first.

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashSet`, then.

Comment: @S.W. but the problem is the running processes are different but the app name is same for more than one

Comment: @sam then you should use package name to classify it instead of process name you mentioned in the code

Comment: @S.W. Yup..sorry for that.. now look at this this is also not working as that way

Comment: m_processesList =AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcesses();
        Set runningApps=new HashSet<>();
        HashSet hashSet=new HashSet();
        hashSet.addAll(m_processesList);
        m_processesList.clear();
        m_processesList.addAll(hashSet);

Comment: runningAppsAdapter=new AppsAdapter(RunningAppsActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,m_processesList);
        m_listView.setAdapter(runningAppsAdapter);
        runningAppsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @sam Please apply Set<String> instead of Set, since even names are same, some contents of the object are different will lead to the Set classify them as different object, unless you simply compare by String

Comment: @sam if you need to store that with Object also, then simply apply HashMap<String, AndroidAppProcess>()

Answer (score 0):

For retrieval of all package name inside your device without duplication, simply apply the following
 1. Add a HashMap variable to store the information

```
private List<PackageInfo> info = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
```

2. Initiate the list in constructor/ inside @Override notifyDataSetChanged method

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = context.getPackageManager()
            .getInstalledPackages(0);
info = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
HashMap<String, PackageInfo> infoList = new HashMap<String, PackageInfo>();
for (PackageInfo s : packages)
    if (!infoList.containsKey(s.packageName)){
        infoList.put(s.packageName, s);
        info.add(s);
    }
```

3. Apply it in getView()

```
processName.setText(info.get(position).packageName);
```

Comment: private void detectApps()
        {

        //TODO: here set the running apps list to the Adapter
        m_processesList =AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcesses();
        Set<AndroidAppProcess> set= new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(m_processesList);
        m_processesList.clear();
        m_processesList.addAll(set);
        runningAppsAdapter=new AppsAdapter(RunningAppsActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,m_processesList);
        m_listView.setAdapter(runningAppsAdapter);
        runningAppsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }